# SQL query INSERT not working inserting values into my DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to insert some values into my DB but it's not working, i'm trying to figure out why it's not working but I'm an amateur php coder,

This is the code I'm using:

```
$insert = mysql_query
    ("
    INSERT INTO news(id,title,body,date,by)
    VALUES ('NULL','".$title."','".$body."','".$date."','".$by."')
    ");
    mysql_close($connect);
```

And the rows i'm trying to insert into are: id,title,body,date,by
but it's not showing up in the database or on my news page.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?  Also, note that if `$title`, etc. come from user input, you will not want to insert directly into query, or you will have a SQL injection vulnerability.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: you might want to mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); to get more information about the error. Also make sure that NULL values are allowed in the column named `id`

Answer (score 7):

`by` is a special keyword.  Try wrapping the column names in tick marks:

```
INSERT INTO news(`id`,`title`,`body`,`date`,`by`)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expect id to be your primary key.  It should not allow a null value.  If it is auto incrementing you might try this:

```
$insert = mysql_query
    ("
    INSERT INTO news(title,body,date, by)
    VALUES ('".$title."','".$body."','".$date."','".$by."')
    ");
```

Others have noted by is a reserved word so you will need to quote it.  It is best to avoid naming database objects using reserved words. Consider renaming the `by` column to `author`.

You should consider making changing the query into a prepared statement. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: NULL is an accepted means of triggering `auto_increment` or `DEFAULT` constraints.  But the OP specified NULL in single quotes, so it'd be interpreted as a string...

Comment: I have run into problems with default and auto_increment constraints when setting them to null, but that was with Oracle via JDBC prepared statements.  I generally, try to avoid specifying columns for which I have or expect no data in queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling mysql_error() to get the error message:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't put the single quotes around NULL or else it will be entered as a string.

Also, I am assuming that you are using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to sanitize $title, $body, etc.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$body  = mysql_real_escape_string($body);
$date  = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
$by    = mysql_real_escape_string($by);
```

As mellamokb pointed out, `by` and `date` are special keywords. It's best practice to put ticks around your columns (and table names). (this will fix your query)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `news` (`id`, `title`, `body`, `date`, `by`) VALUES
      (NULL, '" . $title . "', '" . $body . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $by . "');";
if ($insert = mysql_query($query, $connect)) {
    // Success!
} else {
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error($connect); // this will tell you whats wrong
}
mysql_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) & [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to handle SQL injection attack possibilities:

```
$insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO news
                    (id, title, body, date, `by`)
                   VALUES 
                     (NULL,'%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($title),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($body),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($date),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($by));

$result = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will let you know what error is encountered too.

That said, there are numerous potential issues:

- [by is a reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), you need backticks to escape its use in MySQL (see example above).  The alternative is to rename the column to something that is not a reserved word -- backticking every column and/or table name hides such issues rather than learning
- NULL should not be inside of single quotes, or it will be interpreted as a string; `DEFAULT` would be another option if there's a DEFAULT constraint on the column
- the `date` column should be either a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data type rather than string in order to use [MySQL Date/Time functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), and should be using [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) if the value will not be a MySQL standard date format